# Typescript syntax error on CommonJS/Node module: Unexpected token ':' on function param

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

This file checks out to be valid via TS, no more errors but during runtime, I get Unexpected token ':' on any of the TS I specified such as it immediately errors on `function (err: string)`

Here are my build and start scripts.  I of course run build, then run start:

```
"start": "node  --trace-warnings dist/server.ts",
"build": "NODE_ENV=production webpack -p --env=prod",
```

**api.ts**

```
const _ = require('lodash'),
  companyTable = require('./shared/data/companies.json'),
  countryTable = require('./shared/data/countries.json'),
  compression = require('compression'),
  express = require('express'),
  expressApp = (module.exports = express()),
  historyApi = require('connect-history-api-fallback'),
  oneYear = 31536000;

expressApp.use(compression());

module.exports = expressApp
  .on('error', function (err: string) {
    console.log(err);
  })
  .get('/api/v1/countries', (res: any) => {
    res.json(
      countryTable.map((country: any) => {
        return _.pick(country, ['id', 'name', 'images']);
      })
    );
  })
```

**server.ts**

```
const app = require('./api.js');

const cluster = require('cluster'),
  os = require('os'),
  port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

console.log(port);

if (cluster.isMaster) {
  for (let i = 0; i < os.cpus().length; i++) {
    cluster.fork();
  }
  console.log('Ready on port %d', port);
} else {
  app.listen(port, (err: string) => {
    console.log(`express is listening on port ${port}`);
    if (err) {
      console.log('server startup error');
      console.log(err);
    }
  });
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Visit https://aka.ms/tsconfig.json to read more about this file */
    "target": "es6",                     /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017', 'ES2018', 'ES2019', 'ES2020', or 'ESNEXT'. */
    "module": "es6",                     /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', 'es2020', or 'ESNext'. */
    "lib": ["es6"],                      /* Specify library files to be included in the compilation. */
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowJs": true,                     /* Allow javascript files to be compiled. */
    "checkJs": true,                     /* Report errors in .js files. */
    "jsx": "react",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "sourceMap": true,                   /* Generates corresponding '.map' file. */
    "outDir": "dist",                   /* Redirect output structure to the directory. */
    "rootDir": "./",                     /* Specify the root directory of input files. Use to control the output directory structure with --outDir. */
    "removeComments": true,              /* Do not emit comments to output. */
    "strict": true,                      /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
    "noUnusedLocals": true,                /* Report errors on unused locals. */
    "noUnusedParameters": true,            /* Report errors on unused parameters. */
//    "rootDirs": ["."],                        /* List of root folders whose combined content represents the structure of the project at runtime. */
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],                      /* List of folders to include type definitions from. */
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,  /* Allow default imports from modules with no default export. This does not affect code emit, just typechecking. */
    "preserveSymlinks": true,              /* Do not resolve the real path of symlinks. */
//      "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,                     /* Skip type checking of declaration files. */
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
    },
    "include": [
        "src"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "/node_modules",
        "/src/client/js/ink-config.js",
        "**/test"
  ]
}
```

[image]

UPDATE

So someone pointed out the obvious. Asking why does my dist have a .ts file in it (`server.ts`) and `api.ts`.  That's because I'm copying it over in my webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const TerserJSPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin');
const CopyPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

const isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';

const html = () => {
  return new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
    template: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/client', 'index.html'),
    filename: 'index.html',
    hash: true,
  });
};

const copyAllOtherDistFiles = () => {
  return new CopyPlugin({
    patterns: [
      { from: 'src/client/assets', to: 'lib/assets' },
      { from: 'src/server.ts', to: './' },
      { from: 'src/api.ts', to: './' },
      { from: 'package.json', to: './' },
      { from: 'ext/ink-3.1.10/js/ink-all.min.js', to: 'lib/js' },
      { from: 'ext/ink-3.1.10/js/autoload.min.js', to: 'lib/js' },
      { from: 'ext/js/jquery-2.2.3.min.js', to: 'lib/js' },
      { from: 'ext/ink-3.1.10/css/ink.min.css', to: 'lib/css/ink.min.css' },
      { from: 'feed.xml', to: './' },
      {
        from: 'src/shared',
        to: './shared',
        globOptions: {
          ignore: ['**/*suppressed.json'],
        },
      },
    ],
  });
};

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/client/index.tsx',
  output: {
    filename: 'scripts/app.[hash].bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js'],
  },
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  devServer: {
    writeToDisk: true,
    port: 8080,
  },
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [new TerserJSPlugin({}), new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin({})],
    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
        styles: {
          name: 'styles',
          test: /\.css$/,
          chunks: 'all',
          enforce: true,
        },
      },
    },
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(tsx|ts)?$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'html-loader',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.less$/,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader', 'less-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
            options: {
              hmr: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development',
            },
          },
          'css-loader',
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          outputPath: 'lib/assets/fonts',
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
        use: ['url-loader'],
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: isProduction
    ? [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
          filename: isProduction ? 'lib/css/main.[hash].css' : 'main.css',
        }),
        html(),
        copyAllOtherDistFiles(),
      ]
    : [new CleanWebpackPlugin(), html(), copyAllOtherDistFiles()],
};
```

So...I need to do something different.  While I do need server.ts and api.ts during development, not sure how I can transpile then copy those two files over (ouside of the web bundle I create).

Comment: How are you running this code?

Comment: @awarrier99, from the image, it looks like `node --trace-warnings dist/server.ts`.

Comment: @Tico ah yes, good catch

Comment: No worries, I'm actually starting to learn TS and I'm curious about this one

Comment: I'm confused - why do you have a `.ts` file in your emit directory? Unless you are using something like `ts-node-dev` which transpiles on the fly (which you aren't because you're using `node` in your command, unless you're using babel with the TypeScript preset and haven't shown us that part), you can't process TypeScript

Comment: hmm yea I shouldn't have a .ts fine in my dist right.  Well I'm copying over my server.ts to my dist is the problem.  Let me update my post here

Comment: check out my update @awarrier99

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I'm not entirely sure what the use case for copying over the files directly is - but let me answer by pointing out how you can achieve having the transpiled files in the output directory while still using the original `.ts` source file in development:

First, you can use [`ts-node-dev`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node-dev) in development which helpfully allows you to run the original source files by transpiling on the fly so you can use it just as you would use the `node` binary, but on the source files rather than the emitted files. I use a command similar to this for development: `NODE_ENV=development ts-node-dev --watch ./src/server.ts --transpileOnly ./src/server.ts`

Then, for production, provided that you do not specify the `noEmit` option in your compiler options, TypeScript will transpile and emit files to the provided `outDir`. So, you can run these emitted files using the node binary: `NODE_ENV=production node ./dist/server.js`. This would allow you to remove the files under your source directory from your copy plugin, as TypeScript will transpile and emit the transpiled js in the directory for you

**Edit** (from comments): To include only the files which you want to be transpiled, you can specify those in `include` in your tsconfig:
`include: ['./src/api.ts', './src/server.ts']`

Comment: I copy over files that are not part of src, stuff that are either external libraries or my NodeJS server itself and other root files that wouldn't be picked up by webpack's build and be put as part of the web bundle

Comment: ah so you're saying have TS output my server stuff not webpack.  Sure.  For the other stuff like my ext lib and feed.xhm I'd stll have webpack copy that or just bash script copy those over as they're not part of the bundle.

Comment: I have it as "outDir": "dist" so how would I have TS say copy only transpile my server.ts and api.ts, how would you specify that in your tsconfig.json

Comment: @PositiveGuy yup, so you could include only those specific files. i.e. in your `include` section of your tsconfig specify `['./src/api.ts', './src/server.ts']`

Comment: awesome thanks a lot appreciate it, it wasn't obvious this is what people usually do.

Comment: @PositiveGuy No problem, and much agreed, I found a great guide that someone wrote when I first got started with TypeScript, and if I could find it again I would link it to you

Comment: cool if you ever find that guide would love to have it in your answer too

Comment: hmm I put those two files in my include but it's not outputting to dist even though I set my outDir to "dist".  Furthermore I have the whole "src" in my includes so wouldn't it also output my entire src?  I'm missing something here.  I have "include": [
  "src",
  "./src/api.ts",
  "./src/server.ts"
 ],

Comment: ah maybe you meant to use "files": [ "./src/api.ts", "./src/server.ts" ?  tried that, but it still isn't outputting my api.js and server.js

Comment: webpack is running TS for me via the ts-node plugin in webpack via test: /\.(tsx|ts)?$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',  So I figured this should work, but nothing is outputted yet.  Like I shouldn't have to run TS separate from my webpack build I don't think.

Comment: @PositiveGuy oh I meant to remove `src` from your include entirely, because unfortunately it's not possible to selectively emit for only some of the files in the directory. You'd either have to have TypeScript emit all of the files which it checks, or none of the files which it checks and instead use something like babel to strip out the TypeScript

Comment: @PositiveGuy so ts-loader is an entirely separate thing and shouldn't be used in conjunction with TypeScript emits. Also, since your entry file is specified as the client index file, it will never require or import one of your server files, so those files will never be tested or processed. Usually, I only use webpack to handle my client files and I instead let TypeScript handle the server files

Comment: @PositiveGuy do you need to perform type checks on the entire src directory or just the two api and server files?

Comment: Probably best to [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219077/discussion-between-awarrier99-and-positiveguy) since you have a unique use case and I can then update my answer

Comment: well I figured most people are doing type checks on their entire app.  This is a React App so yes, the entire src too